# Want to get result of SQL query into a variable

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

In this script, I'm trying to get the result of a SQL query into a variable count which I later compare to determine whether to send email.

When I execute the script, I get an `integer expression expected` error.

This is is my script.

```
LOGFILE=/home/ni916c/${SCRIPT}.$RUN_DATE.log
RPTNAME=/home/ni916c/ASPEN_LOADER_error.xls
#rm $LOGFILE
count=$(sqlplus -S ni916c/rajabeta17 <<-EOF
set heading off
        SET FEEDBACK OFF

  SELECT 'Loader File Failed:: '||to_char(load_id) ||'  '|| to_char(file_id) ||'  '||file_name||'  '||to_char(load_status_id) FROM DL_FILES_RECEIVED
  WHERE
 period_id = to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm'))
  and load_status_id=300;
-- in (select load_status_id  from DL_LOAD_STATUS where category like '%ERROR%');
  exit;
  EOF
)
echo "$count" >> $LOGFILE
if [ "$count" -ne 0 ]
then
mailx -s "LOADER ERROR" rk862h@att.com < $LOGFILE
fi
```

Comment: What do you see in the $LOGFILE?

Comment: What line is causing this error?

Comment: i get the result of the query in the log file.
./abcd.sh: line 27: [:
Loader File Failed:: 554187  970  VSTL140117.VSTL140117  300: integer expression expected

Comment: Then it seems you have an SQL problem, not a Bash script problem.  You cannot use an arithmetic test in Bash using a string like that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the error comes from one of two sources :

1. There is a problem in your SQL statement (in which case you should try to debug it outside of the script)
2. It is `if [ "$count" -ne 0 ]` that fails, because your statement does not return an integer.

If the problem is (2) above, you may have to add some kind of error handling to your script to detect unexpected results.  For instance :

```
if
  [[ "$count" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
  # Ok, we have an integer
else
  # Oops, something went wrong
fi
```

You should also make sure that the SQL statement is not returning additional characters that cause the `count` variable not to be recognized as an integer, in which case some trimming might be required.

Comment: i wanted to check whether the query returns any row or not. if it does, then it indicates that there is some error and that error should be mailed. this is what i m trying to implement

Comment: Yes, but are you sure what the request returns actually is an integer?  If there is an error in the request, or if your SQL client formats the result in a way that is not just a raw integer, then your script might choke on that.  Not knowing the exact string returned by your request, I cannot be sure.

Comment: This is the exact string that is being returned by the query.
Loader File Failed:: 554187  970  VSTL140117.VSTL140117  300

Comment: the script worked well after adding the below.
echo "$count" >> $LOGFILE
Linecount=`cat $LOGFILE|wc -l`
if [ $Linecount -gt 1 ]
Thank you Fred for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
result=$(psql -U "$user" -h "$host" -p "$port" -d "$main_schema" -c "select object_version from db_utility.versions" 2>&1)
```

This is the way to get result of postgresql query in bash variable